# After create a normal user in admin page of a Django website, I could not login using that normal user

Tags: django, python-3.7

I use Django 2.2.6 in python 3.7 in windows 10.
After I create a normal user in the admin page in dev mode(127.0.0.0:8000/admin), when I tried to login at front end(127.0.0.0), the normal user I just create could not login. I have tried even the simplest password, but still failed.
However, when I create superuser, it could be used to login to both front end and admin.

form.py:

```
                 <form class="user" method="post">

                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control form-control-user" name="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                               placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" name="password"
                               placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember Me</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                        Login
                    </button>

                    {% if form.errors %}
                    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again. {{form.is_valid}} </p>
                    {% endif %}
                </form>
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import forms
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission


# admin.site.register(Carpark)   => fired bunch of queries, below to mitigate problems
@admin.register(Permission)
class PermissionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.select_related('content_type')


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Carpark)
admin.site.register(User)


# @admin.register(User)
# class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # form = forms.UserChangeForm


@admin.register(Discipline)
class DisciplineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code', 'name', 'person', 'person2', 'carpark')


@admin.register(CourseInfo)
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code', 'title', 'type', 'carpark', 'discipline', 'person', 'pattern', 'available')

    def hop(self, obj):
        return obj.discipline.hop1 if obj.discipline else "-"

    hop.admin_order_field = 'discipline__person'

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Title)
admin.site.register(Material)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include('bm.urls'),),
path('api/v2/', include(router.urls)),
path('api/users/', rest.UserList.as_view()),

path('api/login', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```

When I tried to debug, the front end form throws an error(form.error):

```
    __all__
Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.
```

Comment: did you grant them "Staff status" by clicking that checkbox in the admin?

Comment: @AMG Yes. I even tried to grant them superuser, but still can not login

Comment: https://t.me/python_learners_group/3285

Comment: check in the database, whether the superuser status is updated or not

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan  But even normal user could login on the frontend, no need for superuser, My problem is that I could not login on the front end using any normal user

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan I have checked the database, is indeed superuser, but the password in the database is the one I set in backend, should it be hashed?

Comment: yes. that should be hashed. dont create by yourself, create with the inbuilt register method